# android studio google play-services 8.3 issue

Tags: android, google-analytics, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to add only google-analytics and ads to my app but when I try to add:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'

I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
>   You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>   However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

I have seen many posts regarding this and most suggested adding the full library (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'),

but that is not a solution because of the many permissions play-services requests now.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In the dependencies in your project (not app) build.gradle, update your dependency to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'